# How do assertion libraries such as Chai work without forcing a call to a function?

Tags: javascript, function, assert, assertions, chai

In [Chai](http://chaijs.com/), you can do stuff like the following:

```
expect({}).to.exist;
```

`exist` is not a function call, but this still works in testing frameworks. The opposite (`expect({}).to.not.exist`) causes tests to fail, but again, `exist` is not a function call.

How do these assertions work without making me call a function? In fact, if I try to say `expect({}).to.exist()` the test fails because `exist` is not a function.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I figured it out (or at least, I figured out *a* method). Use [JavaScript getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters):

```
var throws = {
  get a() {
    throw new Error('a');
  },
  get b() {
    throw new Error('b');
  },
  get c() {
    throw new Error('c');
  }
};
```

When doing `throws.a`, `throws.b`, or `throws.c`, the appropriate error will be thrown.

From that point it is rather easy to build the assertions which are contained within Chai.

Comment: How does that explains it? That's a pretty big jump without explaining what happens in the middle

Comment: The linked article really helps explain things if you're not familiar with getters.  The short version is that, thanks to new(-ish) browser improvements, you can now control a property beyond just setting it (eg. `a.b = 5`).  Now, you can define a "getter" method for a property, and when any code tries to read that property's value (eg. `console.log(a.b)`) the browser will run the defined "getter" method.  That method can then trigger logic (eg. Chai's assertion logic).  So when you do a `to.exist`, even though there is no `()` after you *are* still calling a method (the getter method).